# exception in thread main java.util.illegalformatconversionexception d = java.lang.double

Tags: java

Java newbie here, I've been making a program that calculates which option during bus ride is better: single card, month card or a day card. So I get this error:

```
exception in thread main java.util.illegalformatconversionexception d = java.lang.double
```

It has something to do with `d` being a `double` I'm guessing. But `double` should be fine.

Another question is- how do I make the program choose from 2 random cheaper ways if 2 or 3 options are all same cheap?

code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class kt_3_3
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter amount of days:");
        double p = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter amount of rides:");
        double s = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the price of one time ticket:");
        double y = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the price of a day ticket:");
        double d = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the price of a month card:");
        double k = scan.nextDouble();

        if ((y * s) > (p * d)) {

            System.out.printf("Cheaper option is single cards");

        } else if ((p * d) > (y * s)) {

            System.out.printf("Cheaper option is %f day tickets", p);

        } else if ((k > (y * s))) {

            System.out.printf("Cheaper option is a month card");

        } else if ((p * d) > k) {

            System.out.printf("Cheaper option is %f day tickets", p);

        } else if ((y * s) > k) {

            System.out.printf("Cheaper option is single cards");

        } else if (k > (p * d)) {

            System.out.printf("Enter the price of a month card:");

        } else if ((k == (p * d) == (y * s))) { //this doesnt seem to be working

            System.out.printf(""Cheaper option is single cards"")

        }

    }

}
```

I appreciate the help!
Edit: (solved by myself, simply forgot to put the else if statement between additional ()  ) ive spotted another flaw, and that is- if calculates 2 but doesnt take the 3rd one into consideration. For expample: if y * s < p * d but really "k" is the cheapest, it will say that y * s is cheapest. I've tried to use the && to format a 2nd statement there aswell but it throws me "else" without "if", " ; expected" and illegal start of expression.

Edit 2: New code, completly working :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class kt_3_3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter days:");
double p = scan.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Enter amount of drives:");
double s = scan.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Enter one time ticket cost:");
double y = scan.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Enter the cost of a day ticket:");
double d = scan.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Enter the price of a month card:");
double k = scan.nextDouble();

if (((y * s) < (p * d)) && (y * s) < k) {

    System.out.printf("Cheaper way is one time tickets");

} else if (((p * d) < (y * s)) && (p * d) < k) {

    System.out.printf("Cheaper way is %f day tickets", p);

} else if (((k < (y * s))) && k < (p * d)) {

    System.out.printf("cheaper way is a month card");

} else if (((p * d) < k) && (p * d) < (y * s)) {

    System.out.printf("Cheaper way is %f day tickets", p);

} else if (((y * s) < k) && (y * s) < (p * d)) {

    System.out.printf("Cheaper way is one time tickets");

} else if ((k < (p * d)) && k < (y * s)) {

    System.out.printf("cheaper way is a month card");

} else if (((k == (p * d))) && k < (y * s)) {

    System.out.printf("cheaper way is a month card");

} else if (((k == (y * s))) && k < (p * d)) {

    System.out.printf("Cheaper way is a month card");

} else if (((y * s) == (p * d)) && (y * s) < k) {

    System.out.printf("Cheaper way is one time tickets");

}

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if ((k == (p * d) == (y * s)))`

Isn't a valid expression. You can only do 1 comparison per boolean expression so this will evaluate to a boolean === the `y * s` double. You can join them instead. ie

`if (k == (p * d) && k == (y * s))`

Also

`System.out.printf(""Cheaper option is single cards"")`

Is wrong, you only use a single set of `"`'s for strings, and your missing the trailing `;`

Answer (score 0):

`k == (p * d)` gives a boolean (true or false) and then you are trying to compare that boolean to `(y * s)` which is of type double.

Answer (score 0):

In this evaluation compiler first checks left comparison operator (k == (p*d)) and either finds it true or false. In any case the result is boolean. You now want to compare it to a double, which is incorrect. You have to do `if (k == (p * d) && k == (y * s))`.

remember about escape sequences. You need to type `\"` to have literal `"`. Likewise, you would type `\\` for literal `\` in our string.